# get value of object inside array inside object with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have this:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "4831",
    "name": "Rui Vasco Martins",
    "nickname": "rvgmartins",
    "money_start": "10200",
    "balance": "8000"
  }]
}
```

How do I get the value of `data->id`, `data->name`, etc ?

Comment: An object with arrays, with objects...

Comment: Ok, sorry, i'm editing. How shoul i do it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data is multiple. It means it is an array of objects. There's no such things as data->id, only data[ n ]->id. In that case, you might want all possible IDs and you can do it with a traditionnal for loop, or other.

```
var i =0;
var total = object.data.length;
var ids = [];
for(; i < total; i++) {
   ids.push( data[ i ].id );
}
console.log(ids);
```

If you are SURE there's only 1 data entry and will always be, you can be straight forward and go `object.data[ 0 ].id` as well!

Please note that "object" is the variable containing the JSON :)

And for next time, here's a little hint :
http://jsonlint.com/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Your object contains an array, so you need to use the correct indices to further delve into the object; your id and name happen to be in the first array, so we use `obj.data[0]`.

```
var obj = {"data":[{"id":"4831","name":"Rui Vasco Martins","nickname":"rvgmartins","money_start":"10200","balance":"8000","profit":"5010","nreload":"1","deal_id":"4813","created_at":"2015-05-27 12:54:33","updated_at":"2015-07-21 22:31:47"}],"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"services/dashboard","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/pla`in, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

You can use either dot or square bracket notation, to further identify the object property, here's dot notation:

```
var data_id = obj.data[0].id; // "4831"
var data_name = obj.data[0].name; // "Rui Vasco Martins"
```

Here's square-bracket notation:

```
var data_id = obj.data[0]['id']; // "4831"
var data_name = obj.data[0]['name']; // "Rui Vasco Martins"
```

Comment: This answer is correct given the OPs question, but it may not work as expected in all use cases. Depends on what data contains. What if it contains multiple objects in its array? See @Bene answer

Comment: I guess that will be addressed in a follow-up question; I only answer what's asked.

Comment: And JS linter prefer the dot notation, in case the OP takes that answer!

Answer (score 0):

As within `data` there is an array, you can do:

```js
var myJson = {
    "data": [{
        "id": "4831",
            "name": "Rui Vasco Martins",
            "nickname": "rvgmartins",
            "money_start": "10200",
            "balance": "8000",
            "profit": "5010",
            "nreload": "1",
            "deal_id": "4813",
            "created_at": "2015-05-27 12:54:33",
            "updated_at": "2015-07-21 22:31:47"
    }],
        "status": 200,
        "config": {
        "method": "GET",
            "transformRequest": [null],
            "transformResponse": [null],
            "url": "services/dashboard",
            "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        }
    },
        "statusText": "OK"
}
document.write('id: ' + myJson.data[0].id + '</br>name: ' + myJson.data[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's understand your problem. Notes to be taken:

- you have a JSON, which is inside of a variable, I will assume that this variable is `foo`
- there is no such thing as `data->id` in Javascript. If you have an object called `data` and it has a member called `id`, then you reference it as `data.id`
- `name` is inside an array. An element of an array is referenced by an index, which starts from 0, so, your array noted as `data` is an array having a single element, which is the 0th element

So, you can get the `id` with `foo.data[0].id` and you can get the `name` as `foo.data[0].name`. However, as per se, nothing forces your array to have exactly one element. If there are more elements, you need to be able to decide somehow which element's `id` and `name` you are interested in. Also, your array is not forced to have elements at all.

Whenever you see such a JSON, arrays are enclosed inside `[]` brackets and objects are enclosed inside `{}` brackets.

Answer (score 0):

object.data[0].id => for id

object.data[0].name => for name